# If random variables X,Y are independent is $P(X>k)*P(Y>z)=P(X>k,Y>z)$?

Tags: probability, random-variable, independence

If random variables X,Y are independent is $P(X>k)*P(Y>z)=P(X>k,Y>z)$?

I know if X and Y are independent then $P(X=k)*P(Y=z)=P(X=k,Y=z)$

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What do you use as your definition of independence?